# What is the "Golden Age" of 10,000 years in Kaliyuga?

Tags: puranas, kali-yuga, time, brahma-vaivarta-purana

What is the Golden Age of 10,000 years in Kali Yuga as per Brahma-vaivarta Purana's description? What does it mean?

When does it start and what will happen during this period?

Comment: Are you talking about 10,000 years of golden age in Kaliyuga from a Purana where Sri Krishna talks with river Ganga?

Comment: It is mentioned in any puran but it is said for the first 10,000 years.

Comment: Golden Age means to be the end of the Kaliyuga,which is about 5000 years after it's beginning.

Comment: The link you added itself has the answer. Please read the Wikipedia article properly. What is your question here?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma i hv beennhearing repeatedly tyatvwiki is not fully authentic.So if he wants proper citation from that and other scriptures, where's the harm?

Comment: I understood you want to know about the 10,000 years of Golden age in Kaliyuga. So if you can write this clearly in body, your question will be reopened definitely.

Comment: @Pratimaputra The answer is present in the article itself. If the answer is given in the question and asks what is Golden age, there is no point in asking the question. Answer is found already. If we are posting the same answer from question again, it only gives us rep and does no good. It is not useful. I suggest you to read [help/dont-ask]. If answer is provided along with question, it will get closed.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma thnx.i dont know how much authentic wiki is in this regard and was interested in knowing from other scriptures akso as brahmavaivartapurana is one which contains many interpolations

Comment: Yuga system is Puranic and not supported by central Vedanta, hence, added a tag here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just read the Brahma-Vaivarta Purana yourself? Sri Krishna said that the Ganga devi will purify the sinful for the first 5000 years of Kali yuga. Thereafter, the mantra-upasakas of Krishna will take over that role for 10,000 years.

After 10,000 years, the devotees of Krishna will also disappear, and there will be only one caste - the outcaste.

From the reading, there is no golden age. Just a gradual worsening of the world.

Comment: Can you quote the specific lines that say this, please?

Answer (score 1):

That 10000 starting years of the kaliyug are golden is comparative considering what will follow after that.

Not only Bhagwaan Sri-Krishn but also Bhagwaan Shiv says same thing

Bhagwaan Shri Krishn answers to Shri Nand maharaj ji when being asked

> ब्रह्मवैवर्तपुराणम्/खण्डः ४ (श्रीकृष्णजन्मखण्डः)/अध्यायः ०९०
>
> नन्द उवाच
>
> तीर्थान्येतानि सर्वाणि तिष्ठन्त्येव कियद्दिनम् ।
> साधवो ग्राम्यदेवाश्च शास्त्राण्येतानि वत्सक ।। ३१ ।।
>
> श्रीकृष्ण उवाच
>
> कलौ दशसहस्राणि हरिस्तिष्ठति मेदिनीम् ।
> देवानां प्रतिमा बूज्या शास्त्राणि च पुराणकम् ।। ३२ ।।
> तदर्धमपि तीर्थानि गङ्गादीनि सुनिश्चितम् ।
> तदर्ध ग्रामदेवाश्च वेदाश्च विदुषामपि ।। ३३ ।।
> अधर्मः परिबूर्णश्च तदन्ते च कलौ पितः ।
> एकवर्णा भविष्यन्ति वर्णाश्चत्वार एव च ।। ३४ ।।
>
> Nanda said -
> O son for how long the holy places, the ascetic, the village deities and the seriptures would remain on earth during Kaliyuga
>
> Sri Krishn said -
>
> **During Kaliyuga the lord remains on earth for ten thousand years. Till that time the images of the gods and the scriptures beside the Puranas are also adored. For half that period (five thousand years), do Ganga and all other holy places would enjoy their sanctity and for half of that period, the village deities would be adored besides the intellectual and the Vedas**.... O father at the end of Kaliyuga, wickedness would establish itself completely. At that point of time, the people of all the four varifas would become like Shudras..

ALSO

Krishn ji tell almost about the same thing to Shri laadli ji Shrimati Raadhikaa raani in the earlier Chapter 34, Krishn Janm Khand.

> Verse 40 =
>
> कलौ दशसहस्राणि वर्षाणि प्रतिमा मम।।
> तिष्ठन्ति च पुराणानि प्रभावस्तत्र कः कलेः ।।
>
> **In the age of Kali my images shall remain on earth for ten thousand years and for that duration the Puranas will also remains on earth. As such there will be little influence of the age of Kali.**
>
> https://archive.org/details/brahma-vaivarta-purana-all-four-kandas-english-translation/page/290/mode/1up?view=theater

Moreover,

Shiv ji says in the Skand Puran to Shri Hari Vishnu ji, the same thing

> Vaishnav khand > kartik mahatmya
>
> कलौ दशसहस्राणि विष्णुस्त्यजति मेदिनीम् ।
> तदर्द्धं जाह्नवीतोयं तदर्द्धं ग्रामदेवताः ॥ ३२ ॥
>
> 32. **In Kaliyuga Viṣṇu abandons the earth for (after?) ten thousand years, the waters of Gaṅgā for half that period and the rural deities for half of the latter.**
>
> https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371677.html

Even more so..

Even the well known brahmin dvija and a shrewd political scientist, Shriman Chanakya (or VishnuSharma) says the same in his Chanakya-Neeti, although he's not a authority but still...

> https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_major_works/chANakyanItisort.html
>
> कलौ दशसहस्राणि हरिस्त्यजति मेदिनीम् ।
> तदर्धं जाह्नवीतोयं तदर्धं ग्रामदेवताः ॥ ११-०४